# Unable to find the ISO File of Centos 7

Tags: virtualbox, centos-7

I downloaded the CentOS7 from this official source: http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/

But I am unable to find the ISO file on setting up the VHD in Oracle Virtual Box.

[image]

Could anyone guide me here!

Note: I have asked the same question in Ask Ubuntu Platform, but they said Windows or CentOS are off topic. So, I'm asking here!

Steps I followed:

1. Downloaded this iso file package:

   [image]
2. Installed Oracle VM Virtual Box Manager >

   [image]

   Next, given Memory Size as 2048 MB > Create a Virtual Hard Disk Now > Selected "VDI" > 8 GB > Created it!

   [image]
3. Clicked on Start to select ISO File.

   As you seen the Gif Image like I'm unable to find the iso file to add in Virtual Box VDI which looks like:

   [image]

Comment: In the "Select Installation Media" screen have you clicked the little folder icon on the right and browsed to the location of your downloaded file?

Comment: From your too-fast GIF I think that you are choosing some image from within the ISO. Just specify the entire ISO file that you downloaded.